# GoBackAsync() goes back 2 pages instead of 1. Prism Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to pass parameters back to a view using `GoBackAsync()`. All my view modelas inherit a `BaseViewModel` which inherits `INavigatedAware`.

The navigation path to the last page where I go back is as follows:

NavigationPage/TabbedView -> ViewA -> ViewB -> ViewC

ViewC is a `ListView` and when I select an item from the view `GoBackAsync()` is called passing the item `object` back to the previous view.

**Actual Behaviour**:
When `GoBackAsync()` is called I am taken from ViewC to ViewB to ViewA.

**Expected Behaviour**:
When `GoBackAsync()` is called I land on View B from View C.

#### ViewAViewModel

```
private async void ViewAToViewB()
{
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewB", useModalNavigation:false);
}
```

#### ViewBViewModel

```
private async void ViewAToViewC()
{
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewC", useModalNavigation:false);
}

public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    if (parameters.Count > 0)
    {
        var myString = parameters.GetValue<string>("testParam");
    }
}
```

#### ViewCViewModel

```
private async void NavigateBackToViewB()
{
    var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters();
    navigationParams.Add("testParam", "Adam Sandler");
   await _navigationService.GoBackAsync(navigationParams, useModalNavigation:false);
}
```

#### Temporary fix

In `ViewAViewModel.cs` I have had to prefix *ViewB* with *NavigationPage/* and then set ViewB.xaml and ViewC.xaml to have `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar = false` to stop 2 navigations bars showing.

This is the only way my `GoBackAsync()` goes to ViewB from ViewC and not all the way back to ViewA.

Comment: how are you navigating to view A and view B

Comment: @ebk that has been added to the question now! let me know if anything else is required, thanks.

Comment: we need your whole ViewBViewModel code

Comment: Kindly share TabbedView (ViewModel) code...As it is important to understand how you are navigating from TabbedView > ViewA

Comment: Any chance solving this ? I have more or less the same issue and i can't seem to fix this behaviour, not even by using the app NavigationPage/ as suffix

Comment: @StefanoDriussi instead of using `NavigationPage/TabbedView` I wrapped each `TabPage` child element in a `NavigationPage` that should give your more control not over navigation but also title and icons for each of your tab views.

Comment: @steve thanks for the reply. In the end i've done something similar to your suggestion and it works. Still i don't get why if i create a totally new app with the same hierarchy, back navigation works as expected.